How does oxygen binding alter the electron configuration and magnetic properties of hemoglobin?
• What is the electron configuration of the iron ion in deoxyhemoglobin, and how does this configuration contribute to its paramagnetic nature?
Unfortunately I only find very rudimentary explanations of this in the articles describing the BOLD method. Therefore, I would really really really appreciate any insights into the underlying quantum mechanical principles that govern these changes. Thankssssss

This is a duplicate of a question you asked which was closed.  It's considered very bad behavior on the site to repost a closed question.  You should make edits to the original and it will automatically be submitted to a review queue where members can vote on whether to reopen it or not.

It comes down to $\mathrm{Fe}^{2+}+\mathrm{O}_2\rightleftharpoons\mathrm{Fe}^{3+}+\mathrm{O}_2^-$.
